# Notation of topological space under group action

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I met the following notation in a book I was reading which I've never seen before

$$A \times_{G}B$$

Here $G$ is a group, $A,B$ are topological spaces. How do we define this notation?

P.S. I have a guess according to the context but I'm not sure if it is right. In the context there is a group action of $G$ on both $A$ and $B$. Is this space defined to be the orbit space of the product space $A \times B$?

Comment: Look at the list of symbols at the end of the book.

Comment: @azif00 The author just assume everyone knows this and there's no list of symbols in this book...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4180858/169085

Answer (score 2):

Here $A,B$ are $G$-spaces and
$$A\times_GB=(A\times B)/G$$
is the quotient by the diagonal $G$-action on $A\times B$. To make sense of this you should assume that $G$ acts on both $A,B$ either from the left, or from the right.

On the other hand this notation is most frequently encountered when $A$ is a *right* $G$-space and $B$ is a *left* $G$-space. Then $A$ is turned into a left $G$-space by letting $g\cdot a=ag^{-1}$, and the construction is the same. Thus in this case $A\times_GB$ is the quotient of $A\times B$ by the $G$-action
$$g\cdot (a,b)=(ag^{-1},gb).$$

Comment: In the latter case, it can also be considered the quotient $(A\times B)/\sim$ by the equivalence relation $(ag,b)\sim(a,gb)$. I like that this illustrates the similarity to extension-of-scalars for rings (constructed using tensor products).