# What is the opposite to "discretization"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continuity, soft-question, terminology, word-problem

Solving an initially continuous problem using discrete math tools is known as "[discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization)".

Does the opposite option of using continuous tools to solve discrete problems have a name? And if not, is there any reason why?

---

Coming from natural language processing, that would apply for instance to resorting to [word-embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding), where one expresses words as vectors in order to escape from the essentially discrete nature of word combinatorics. In econometrics, that could apply to the standard modelling of [discrete choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice), where a fictional continuous quantity (utility) is maximised... and the list probably goes on for ever.

Comment: It is sometimes called extrapolation. I used to work in fixed-income derivatives and we would take a discrete (finite) set of bonds and generate a yield curve that was continuous. We referred to the operation as curve cooking.

Comment: taking the continuum limit

Comment: One can consider iterating the time-$1$ map of a flow, as well as first return maps, as time discretizations. In this case the suspension construction could be considered as the opposite of time discretization.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4180858/169085

Comment: @user619894 There is not necessarily any idea of limit involved, as show the two exemples I mentioned.

Comment: In the context of [Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) it is interpolation

Comment: @reuns I guess that interpolation indeed covers a large class of "continualization" techniques.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be an embedding as you already wrote. Check this Wikipedia entry: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding

The function or process could be called embedding or maybe continuity approximation.

Comment: this belongs in a comment